# Working with an uploading Photos in Photo album to the UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, photosframework

I started learning *Swift* and currently enrolled in class which is to build an app for ios. I tried to fetch photos and put them on the collectionview and it worked fine on a simulator of *Xcode*. However, I found out that the `collectionView` does not even load when I tried it on the *iPhone*. The code for requesting an image is like this.

```
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
```

The request options:

```
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
    if let fetchResult :PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image , options: fetchOptions) {

        if fetchResult.countOfAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image) > 0 {

            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{

                imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {image, Error in
                self.imageArray.append(image!)
                self.PHArray.append(fetchResult.object(at: i))
                    print("Success")
                })

            }
```

Somehow in *iPhone* it would still request the photos but would not show the `collectionView`.  I'm very new to coding and I am not sure if this is an appropriate. It would be very Pleased and any sincere advice would be welcomed.

Comment: And what's happening? Does you `print("Success")` fire? I expect if it does that you need to reload the collection view with `.reloadData()`

Comment: Do you  whether its  Printing tremendously? It is taking way too long for them to be uploaded when there are more pictures. I tried it but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

var images:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

```
func fetchPhotos ()
{
    images = NSMutableArray()
  //  totalImageCountNeeded = 3
    self.fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(0)
}

func fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(index:Int)
{
    let status : PHAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    if status == PHAuthorizationStatus.Authorized
    {
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()
    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.synchronous = true

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: true)]

    if let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions)
    {
        if fetchResult.count > 0
        {
            imgManager.requestImageForAsset(fetchResult.objectAtIndex(fetchResult.count - 1 - index) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSizeMake(self.img_CollectionL.frame.size.height/3, self.img_CollectionL.frame.size.width/3), contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (image, _) in
                //self.images.addObject(image!)
                if image != nil
                {
                    self.images.addObject(image!)
                }
                if index + 1 < fetchResult.count && self.images.count < 20 //self.totalImageCountNeeded
                {
                    self.fetchPhotoAtIndexFromEnd(index + 1)
                }
                else
                {
                    print("Completed array: \(self.images)")
                }
            })
            self.img_Collection.reloadData()
        }
    }
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                           numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
{
   return images.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                           cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell 
{
   let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
   let imagess_ : UIImageView = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UIImageView
   imagess_.image = images [indexPath.row] as? UIImage
        return cell
}
```